# How can I rotate 3d object using right and left arrows in Swift? (SceneKit)

Tags: swift, scenekit

**How can I enable the user to move the object using the right and left arrows I put below, instead of manually moving it?**

**"allowscameracontrol" allows the user to rotate the object with their hand. But I just want it to be rotated using arrows.**
** -> sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true**

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       // 1: Load .obj file
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "converse_obj.obj")
        
       //Add camera node
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
       //Place camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 35)
        //*Set camera on scene
        scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
      //Adding light to scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light?.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 35)
        scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
        
        // 6: Creating and adding ambien light to scen
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light?.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light?.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
        


        // Allow user to manipulate camera
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        

        
        // Set background color
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        // Allow user translate image
        sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = false
        
        // Set scene settings
        sceneView.scene = scene
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Hint: `CATransform3DRotate(_:_:_:_:_:)`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SceneKit before.

I'm not sure if you would want to rotate your camera or rotate the node that contains the object. From the way it's named, it makes it sound like `allowsCameraControl` rotates the camera. In any case you would use `rotationMatrixAroundZ` to create a rotation matrix, and then multiply that by the matrix for whichever thing you want to rotate.

If rotating the camera is what you want to do, your code might look like this:

```
func rotateCameraZByDegrees(_ zRotation: Double) {
    let radians = zRotation / 180.0 * Double.pi
    let rotationZ = rotationMatrixAroundZ(radians: radians)
    
    cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(simd_mul(simd_float4x4(cameraNode.transform), rotationZ))
}
```

If you instead want to rotate your object's node, and your object's node is named `sneakersNode`, change the last line to:

```
    sneakersNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(simd_mul(simd_float4x4(sneakersNode.transform), rotationZ))
```

Comment: I would think that the `allowsCameraControl` setting would apply a rotation to the camera node's transform, like the code above does. Thus you should be able to use both finger-based rotation and your arrows if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This post [31881911] in stackO shows you some examples for arrow keys.

Turn allowsCameraControl = false

This post [68506605] see my answer - creating a camera control class makes things a lot easier.

For your rotation, just rotate the object directly - several ways to do this.

```
func resetRotation()
    {
        for (_, vNode) in displayNodes
        {
            vNode.node.removeAllActions()
        }
        vRotate0 = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 2)
        vRotate1 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(450)), z: 0, duration: 3)
        vRotate2 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90)), z: 0, duration: 1)
        vRotate3 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45)), y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
        vRotate4 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(45)), y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
        
        seq = SCNAction.sequence([vRotate0, vRotate1, vRotate2, vRotate3, vRotate4, vRotate3, vRotate4])
        allSeq = SCNAction.repeatForever(seq)
        for (_, vNode) in displayNodes
        {
            vNode.node.runAction(allSeq)
        }
    }
```

You could use some sequences - so your object could do a 360 and stop, come back 90 at a slower pace, whatever you want.  The above repeats forever, but you can take that out.

Or just on Left key press, rotate Y += n degrees.